# 5.1 surround through home theater

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, spdif

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to use my home theater system on my pc. It's connected through S/PDIF however in the sound settings it only sees it as stereo. I played a surround sound test on youtube, and my computer is only using left, right, and center. It's playing low frequency sound through the sub, but its not detecting it as its own channel. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get 5.1 surround through SPDIF as its only supported on PCM encoding, and PCM only support stereo up to 24bit/192khz.

AC3 and DTS encoding support surround, this post should solve your problem (theoretically), as in installs an AC3 plugin that should allow you to play 5.1 surround through SPDIF.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DigitalAC-3Pulseaudio

In lot of cases your would require to always keep pavucontrol up. That's right - Just don't close it.

Select one of the two Digital Surround 5.1 profile options (one includes Analog input) under the built-in audio section under the configuration tab of pavucontrol then DON'T CLOSE that app, you will get working 5.1 audio in all other programs.

If you close it, you won't get the surround sound.

One last tip, don't use youtube for surround testing, it doesn't support it, use this link, u'll download a test video file that works really well.

http://www.tfm.ro/win32-projects/test-avi-ac3/

Comment: Thank you for your response. Following the directions on that post, under "build plugin" when i enter cd alsa-plugins-*, the terminal just tells me no such file or directory.

Comment: U should run this command right after running the command for "Get source for plugin", this line "apt-get source libasound2-plugins" will download the plugin source code and that will create the alsa-plugins directory. Try listing all files and folders in the temp folder u created.

Comment: The files created in the temp folder are: alsa-plugins_1.0.27.orig.tar.bz2; alsa-plugins_1.0.27-2ubuntu2.debian.tar.gz; alsa-plugins_1.0.27-2ubuntu2.dsc

Comment: In addition to the files you should have one folder as "alsa-plugins-1.0.27" it seems u r not able to unpack the downloaded plugin source files, did u get any errors while running the "apt-get source libasound2-plugins" command?

Comment: I ran through the first few sets of commands on the terminal again, "apt-get source libasound2-plugins" it skipped the already downloaded files, then I got some lines saying: "sh: 1: dpkg-source: not found", "Unpack command 'dpkg-source -x alsa-plugins_1.0.27-2ubuntu2.dsc' failed. "Check if the 'dpkg-dev' package is installed." and lastly "E: Child process failed"

Comment: I installed dpkg-dev, and I ran "apt-get source libasound2-plugins" again. I seem to be making progress now.

Comment: Next hiccup is at the "build plugin step. I enter "./configure" and it says "no package 'alsa' found" I then enter "sudo apt-get install alsa" and it says "Note, selecting 'alsa-base' instead of 'alsa'
alsa-base is already the newest version."

Comment: sorry for delay, was away for some time, any luck with this issue?